# How can I write this in better using javascript and/or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, coding-style

I am refactoring some old PHP/js/jquery/Perl/etc code.

Can anyone suggest a simpler clearer way of doing what this accomplishes?  Basically, it captures a value between 1 and 8 selected by radio button which is then picked up by a javascript function fired when the form containing it is activated.  I'm fairly new to all of this.

The system as a whole is mostly PHP

````
<!-- SENDER: NUM PASSENGER (RADIO) BUTTON -->
<td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;color: #000000">
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr1" value="1" type="radio" checked="checked"
                                                           onClick="insphv(1)">1
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr2" value="2" type="radio" onClick="insphv(2)">2
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr3" value="3" type="radio" onClick="insphv(3)">3
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr4" value="4" type="radio" onClick="insphv(4)">4
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr5" value="5" type="radio" onClick="insphv(5)">5
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr6" value="6" type="radio" onClick="insphv(6)">6
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr7" value="7" type="radio" onClick="insphv(7)">7
  <input name="passgr" id="passgr8" value="8" type="radio" onClick="insphv(8)">8
  <input type="hidden" name="tpassenger" id="tpassenger" />```
                  </td>

        var passgrval=0;
<!-- RECEIVER: NUM PASSENGER (RADIO) BUTTON -->
        if        (document.getElementById('passgr1').checked) {
                passgrval=1;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr2').checked) {
                passgrval=2;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr3').checked) {
                passgrval=3;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr4').checked) {
                passgrval=4;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr5').checked) {
                passgrval=5;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr6').checked) {
                passgrval=6;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr7').checked) {
                passgrval=7;
        } else if (document.getElementById('passgr8').checked) {
                passgrval=8;
        }
````

Comment: what is inside `insphv` function?

Comment: Yes, much simpler. Assign a single shared class among all of the `passgr` inputs, then loop through them in JS to find out which one is checked. Then, you can remove the `id` attribute from all of them. Or, you can use jQuery to find the checked one pretty easily `$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()`

Answer (score 1):

You might use event delegation instead - add a change listener and look to see if the target is one of the `<input>`s, and if so, check its value:

```js
var passgrval = 0;
window.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('[name=passgr]')) {
    passgrval = e.target.value;
    console.log(passgrval);
  }
});
```

````html
<td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;color: #000000">
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=1 checked>1
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=2>2
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=3>3
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=4>4
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=5>5
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=6>6
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=7>7
  <input type="radio" name="passgr" value=8>8
  <input type="hidden" name="tpassenger" id="tpassenger" />```
</td>
````

Or, even better, if at all possible, instead of reassigning `passgrval`, only *retrieve* the currently checked input value when it's needed for processing:

```
const val = document.querySelector('[name=passgr]:checked').value;
```